# ZBAR unable to scan PDF-417 iOS

Tags: ios, barcode, zbar

I am using Zbar for my iOS barcode scanning app but the problem is it is not detecting pdf-417 type of barcodes. I've installed ZBAR app for iPhone it is also unable to detect pdf417. But in zbar symbols structure pdf 417 is added. I also tried to enable pdf-417 explicitly by this line of code, but no luck.

```
     [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_PDF417 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 1];
```

Any help?

Comment: Been trying to get this to work for days. Good to finally find out ZBar simply doesn't support it.

Answer (score 4):

Zbar scanner support only some specific bar code types.

It supports bar code formats such us **AN-13/UPC-A, UPC-E, EAN-8, Code 128, Code 39, Interleaved 2 of 5 and QR Code.**

Refer to this site: http://zbar.sourceforge.net/

For **PDF-417 bar** code some separate SDK is available it seems. It will support the bar code such us **Pdf417, QrCode, LicenseInfo, Code128, Code39, EAN13, EAN8, ITF, UPC and UPCE.**

https://github.com/PDF417/pdf417-ios

Customize this one with the config type:

```
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_PDF417 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 1];
```

Just try with all the config type and check.

```
typedef enum zbar_config_e {
    ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE = 0,        /**< enable symbology/feature */
    ZBAR_CFG_ADD_CHECK,         /**< enable check digit when optional */
    ZBAR_CFG_EMIT_CHECK,        /**< return check digit when present */
    ZBAR_CFG_ASCII,             /**< enable full ASCII character set */
    ZBAR_CFG_NUM,               /**< number of boolean decoder configs */

    ZBAR_CFG_MIN_LEN = 0x20,    /**< minimum data length for valid decode */
    ZBAR_CFG_MAX_LEN,           /**< maximum data length for valid decode */

    ZBAR_CFG_UNCERTAINTY = 0x40,/**< required video consistency frames */

    ZBAR_CFG_POSITION = 0x80,   /**< enable scanner to collect position data */

    ZBAR_CFG_X_DENSITY = 0x100, /**< image scanner vertical scan density */
    ZBAR_CFG_Y_DENSITY,         /**< image scanner horizontal scan density */
} zbar_config_t;
```

Comment: Yeah I've seen pdf-417 but it is not free for commercial app. And for zbar it is giving these options
http://screencast.com/t/HnviRi8Q9

Comment: Then sorry Zbar doesn't support.

Comment: Yes.Is there any way I can fix this or add this functionality?

Comment: I've done that but it is not working and [scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_PDF417 config:ZBAR_CFG_ADD_CHECK to:0]; it will be [scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_PDF417 config:ZBAR_CFG_ADD_CHECK to:1];

Comment: Yes i have already done this but it is not working. I've pointed it on my question.

Comment: [scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_PDF417 config:ZBAR_CFG_ADD_CHECK to:0]; like this ....

Comment: No it is not working either and the value will be 1 to activate and 0 to deactivate.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using iOS7 or above, you don't have to rely on third-party libraries like ZBar. [AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/index.html) has built-in support for detecting 1D and 2D barcodes including PDF417 and QR codes using the device camera. [AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject_Class/index.html) does the trick.

You can find working examples [here](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2013/10/10/scanning-barcodes-with-ios-7-objective-c.aspx) and [here](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2013/10/11/ios7-day-by-day-day-16-decoding-qr-codes-with-avfoundation).